# List events facebook by city

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can list the facebook event by creator:

```
SELECT name, start_time, venue FROM event WHERE creator = :ID_CREATOR
```

Now, I want to list all the facebook event by city.

Already I sought everywhere and found nothing.

Comment: FQL is going away anyways.

Comment: This is not available anymore. There used to be a 'location' field available on the event but that has been deprecated.